# Need voice recognition without Google dialog box

Tags: android, dialog, voice, voice-recognition

Has anyone found a way to do perform speech recognition without displaying Google's voice recognition dialog box?  Can this be suppressed during recognition, or if not, hidden from view?  I would still need to be able to initiate the voice capture, detect the silence to let me know the capture is complete, then convert to text.

Comment: Presumably you can use the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html directly, with your own UI?

Answer (score 0):

The RecognitionListener class, as you will see in this post [How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)s, the RecognitionListener class has some methods called  onReadyForSpeech(), onBeginningOfSpeech(), onEndOfSpeech() etc, which basically tell you when the user has started, ended speaking and the recognized result. You can do whatever you want in the process by overriding these methods, either showing a dialog or doing another thing to warn the user he should start speaking.