# How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech

Is this possible without modify the android APIs?
I've found a article about this. 
There's one a comment that I should do modifications to the android APIs.
But it didn't say how to do the modification.
Can anybody give me some suggestions on how to do that?
Thanks!

---

I've found this article;
[SpeechRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559930/speechrecognizer-causes-anr-i-need-help-with-android-speech-api) 
His needs is almost the same as mine.
It is a good reference for me!

---

I've totally got this problem solved.
I googled a usable sample code [from this China website](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_6f8d8d8e0100t7t7.html)
Here's my source code

```
package voice.recognition.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.util.Log;



public class voiceRecognitionTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

   private TextView mText;
   private SpeechRecognizer sr;
   private static final String TAG = "MyStt3Activity";
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);     
            mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);     
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
            sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());        
   }

   class listener implements RecognitionListener          
   {
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
            }
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
            }
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
            }
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
            }
            public void onEndOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
            }
            public void onError(int error)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG,  "error " +  error);
                     mText.setText("error " + error);
            }
            public void onResults(Bundle results)                   
            {
                     String str = new String();
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
                     ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                     for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
                     {
                               Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
                               str += data.get(i);
                     }
                     mText.setText("results: "+String.valueOf(data.size()));        
            }
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
            }
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
            }
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5); 
                     sr.startListening(intent);
                     Log.i("111111","11111111");
            }
   }
}
```

Be sure to delete the annoying Logs after debugging!

Comment: It's definitely possible to do, as I've seen other apps do it (Voice infinity) but as for how, I haven't a clue.  I'd imagine you could start by downloading the android source and checking in the api where the voice is, and then experiment extending...

Comment: as noted by Femi, make sure to have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml file otherwise SpeechRecognizer will not pick up any audio

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use the [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) interface. Your app needs to have the RECORD_AUDIO permission, and you can then create a SpeechRecognizer, give it a [RecognitionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html) and then call its `startListening` method. You will get callbacks to the listener when the speech recognizer is ready to begin listening for speech and as it receives speech and converts it to text.

Comment: also don't forget to destroy SpeechRecognier in OnDestroy() method as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19931355/2048266 to not get `has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$Connection@414f0e40 that was originally bound here` error

Comment: Can you please show me an example? Also, can I use this while the screen is off?

Answer (score 7):

[GAST](https://github.com/gast-lib) has a handy abstract class you can use to use the `SpeechRecognizer` class with very little new code. There is also an example of running the `SpeechRecognizer` as a background service using [this](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/activation/WordActivator.java) and [this](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/activation/SpeechActivationService.java)

Comment: Would you mind guiding me on how to implement them into the MainActivity?  What does this mean "* Use {@link Intent}s to start and stop it?"   Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please show me an example? Also, can I use this while the screen is off?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for posting this! I found it helpful to define the onclick listener in oncreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);     
    MyRecognitionListener listener = new MyRecognitionListener();
    sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
    sr.setRecognitionListener(listener);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);    
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,1); 
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");
                sr.startListening(intent);
        }
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**I end up making Github project to convert Text to speech and speech to text without annoying dialog,**

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-TTS-STT/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/hiteshsahu/stt_tts/translation_engine

```
 //SPEECH TO TEXT DEMO
    speechToText.setOnClickListener({ view ->

        Snackbar.make(view, "Speak now, App is listening", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()

        TranslatorFactory
                .instance
                .with(TranslatorFactory.TRANSLATORS.SPEECH_TO_TEXT,
                        object : ConversionCallback {
                            override fun onSuccess(result: String) {
                                sttOutput.text = result
                            }

                            override fun onCompletion() {
                            }

                            override fun onErrorOccurred(errorMessage: String) {
                                erroConsole.text = "Speech2Text Error: $errorMessage"
                            }

                        }).initialize("Speak Now !!", this@HomeActivity)

    })


    //TEXT TO SPEECH DEMO
    textToSpeech.setOnClickListener({ view ->

        val stringToSpeak :String = ttsInput.text.toString()

        if (null!=stringToSpeak &&  stringToSpeak.isNotEmpty()) {

            TranslatorFactory
                    .instance
                    .with(TranslatorFactory.TRANSLATORS.TEXT_TO_SPEECH,
                            object : ConversionCallback {
                                override fun onSuccess(result: String) {
                                }

                                override fun onCompletion() {
                                }

                                override fun onErrorOccurred(errorMessage: String) {
                                    erroConsole.text = "Text2Speech Error: $errorMessage"
                                }

                            })
                    .initialize(stringToSpeak, this)

        } else {
            ttsInput.setText("Invalid input")
            Snackbar.make(view, "Please enter some text to speak", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    })
```

[image]