# Voice recognition for alQuran Arabic

Tags: android, voice-recognition

How can we compare two audio files, or voice recorder files, according to `Al-Quran`.
`Al-Quran` has special pronunciation compared to `Arabic` pronunciation.
Is it possible to do the comparison between user voice and the way `Al-Quran` is pronounced?

I have already tried the `Google Speech to Text for Arabic`, but it seems it does not handle the pronunciation for `Al-Quran`.

For example this audio (Al-Quran's recite)

[Quran1](https://soundcloud.com/hazman-badrunsham/abdi)

[Quran2](https://soundcloud.com/hazman-badrunsham/eisom)

Comment: maybe it can help for new idea https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5156172

Comment: @mesutpiskin I need to sign in to see the content and need purchasing.

Comment: Have you tried any kind of machine learning algorithms ?

Comment: See [Al-quran_learning with M.S.R. overview](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269037538_Al-quran_learning_using_mobile_speech_recognition_An_overview) and [Quranic Verses Verification using Speech Recognition Techniques](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282456596_Quranic_Verses_Verification_using_Speech_Recognition_Techniques)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub

Comment: please share the difference in the pronunciation of the 2 words in audio file so we can hear difference and test on our own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comparing two audio files is that much easy, but if you want to analyse the `Thajweed` (Proper Pronunciation) of **Quran** according to the legal way of Arabic grammar, you have to use some kind of machine learning techniques such as [Audio Classifications](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition).

In order to use ML you need to get more than 1000 sample voices of Quran verses recordings with proper pronunciation to compare the current voice and detect the `Thajweed` mistakes, I'm happy if you could build an AI to detect that, but it requires more time and resources than you expect.

**In simple:** There is an Android library called `musicg` which you can use to compare two audio files and get the similarity percentage between them. (It may or may not give 100% accuracy in your case)

> Give file path, URI or bytes array to Wave class : in my case I've given InputStream

```
Wave wave = new Wave(getAssets().open("quran_verse_25.wav"));
Wave wave1 = new Wave(getAssets().open("test_audio.wav"));

FingerprintSimilarity fingerprintSimilarity = wave.getFingerprintSimilarity(wave1);
float score = fingerprintSimilarity.getScore();
float similarity = fingerprintSimilarity.getSimilarity();

Log.d("Similarsound", "Time Match: " + fingerprintSimilarity.getsetMostSimilarTimePosition() + " Score : " + score + " Similarity : " + similarity);
```

The library can be download through this [URL](https://code.google.com/archive/p/musicg/).

Comment: it same with the Shazam apps?

Comment: @Zuhrain, I don't have experiance with the App you refered brother, I've never seen any applications using ML or AI to detect the Quran pronunciation, I believe that they also may be using the same `MUSICG` library.

Comment: is there any tutorial to apply the musicg?

Comment: Yeah that's what I posted the code in my answer, that's the same code base for Android just download their JAR file in the given website and start coding, if you need any clarification just ask me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190608/discussion-between-googlian-and-zuhrain).

Comment: I was trying to implement this https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1684889 probably wth LSTM @Googlian do you think it's feasible