# Android RecognizerIntent Speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, recognizer-intent

How to handle the visibility of an image(ImageView) in the event the RecognizerIntent finishes due to the user not speaking

```
if (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS == null){
image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);///microphone icon
}
```

or

```
if (RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH == null){
image1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);///microphone
}
```

thnx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the code above you are just testing if the constants are null, which they are not. You have to start the recognition somewhere in the code by

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    //... put other settings in the Intent 
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

and receive the result in

```
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
          //... do your stuf with results
         }
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
```

A more customizable way is to use SpeechRecognizer directly. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones).