# android voice recognition vs SpeechRecognizer

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition

I am working on speech to text function, and beforehand I used the Voice Recognition where a Google Dialog box will popup when the system is recognizing the speech.

Subsequently, since I do not want the dialog box, I have followed the answer in 
[How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

implementing the `SpeechRecognizer` such that there would be no that standard google dialog popup when the speakbutton is pressed.

### Codes:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button_record) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "zh_HK");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,1); 
        sr.startListening(intent);
        Log.i("111111","11111111");
    }
```

and in the `class listener implements RecognitionListener`

```
    public void onResults(Bundle results)                   
    {
         String str = new String();
         Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
         ArrayList<String> data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
         string_after_speech = data.get(0).toString();
         TextView1.setText(""+string_after_speech);
```

### Questions:

1. I expect the results generated from Voice Recognition (the one with the Google dialog box popup) and SpeechRecognizer should be the same? Yet running several times, it seems that the quality from the Voice Recognition with Dialog Box higher than that of SpeechRecognizer...
2. How could limit the result to be SOLELY zh_HK (Cantonese or Traditional Chinese)? I tried saying a speech in Cantonese but it generated a result half in Chinese and half in English...If I speak English, it outputs English directly. Is the `intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "zh_HK"` set in this way not correct?

Thanks!

Comment: About question 2.: I think it should be "zh-HK" instead

Comment: it is not working too