# Speech recognition without Google dialog boxes

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech

I will try to use the Speech recognition without Google dialog boxes with RecognitionListener
but does not works only beep when start the application.I have added permissions Audio record and Internet into the manifest file.I hope you tell me and help me to find the wrong...I have not errors on Log cat...I want to make a loop when user say hello a Toast show up a mesage Regognition OK and a list view shows the results.

```
 public  class MainActivity extends Activity  implements RecognitionListener
{

 private ListView wordsList;

private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
private Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent; 


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                                     RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                                     this.getPackageName());

    wordsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); 

    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

}


    public void onBeginningOfSpeech(){ }

        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer){ }

        public void onEndOfSpeech(){ }

        public void onError(int error){

           //mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

    }

    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params){ }


    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults){ }


    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params){


        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Voice recording starts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onResults(Bundle results)
    {

        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);


        wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  matches));


        if ( matches.contains("hello") {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recognision OK!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }

    }

    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) { }

  }
```

Comment: try using matches.get(0) in onResult

Comment: I do not think this is the problem...because at the start of speech do not shows the Toast "Voice recording starts"...I use Samsung S4...

Comment: See tutorial: http://www.truiton.com/2014/06/android-speech-recognition-without-dialog-custom-activity/ at Truiton

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've missed:

```
mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener();
```

The parameter will be either be the context which implements the listener, or the custom listener you've created.

At the moment your code is not setting the listener, you just have the listener code.

Edit: If you do not implement `RecognitionListener`, then you can do it this way:

```
mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onBufferReceived(byte[] arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onEndOfSpeech() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(int arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onResults(Bundle results) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                            });
```

Comment: Ok mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener); what I must put for listener?

Comment: Since your code `implements RecognitionListener` I assume `this` would be the correct usage. I'll edit my answer to show another way.

Comment: Ok works mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this); Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: How I can make loop auto speech every x secs?

Answer (score 15):

try this code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class VoiceRecognitionActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

    private TextView returnedText;
    private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
    private Intent recognizerIntent;
    private String LOG_TAG = "VoiceRecognitionActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_recognition);
        returnedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
        recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,"en");
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,this.getPackageName());
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,this.getPackageName());

recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    speech.stopListening();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (speech != null) {
            speech.destroy();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setMax(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int errorCode) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
        returnedText.setText(errorMessage);
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResults");
        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        String text = "";
        for (String result : matches)
            text += result + "\n";

        returnedText.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
        progressBar.setProgress((int) rmsdB);
    }

    public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
        String message;
        switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

activity_voice_recognition.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rakesh.voicerecognitionexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".VoiceRecognitionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_voice_recognition" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: great answer. In android 6 its important to ask permission `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` before using voice api