# How to remove or hide google dialog box in android?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I'm creating a application using android studio, so it's actually a voice recognition app. My app is working well, but i have a problem with google dialog box or google speaking dialog box, I don't have any idea how to remove or hide the dialog. I'm new in creating a android app. And also I've searched in google and nothing helped me.

This is my app image

[image]

When i press the button it will show a google dialog box or speaking dialog box.

It will show the dialog box

[image]

Now i want is to remove or to hide that dialog. I want is to when i click the button, you can speak without showing that dialog.
I don't have any idea how to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speech recognition without Google dialog boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724471/speech-recognition-without-google-dialog-boxes)

Comment: I'll try this, Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

Answer (score 2):

The followign code will start speech recognation with out a prompt

```
public class VoiceRecognitionActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

    private TextView returnedText;
    private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView imageView1;
    private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
    private Intent recognizerIntent;
    private String LOG_TAG = "VoiceRecognitionActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_recognition);
        returnedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
        recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
        //recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,this.getPackageName());
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    speech.stopListening();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (speech != null) {
            speech.destroy();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setMax(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int errorCode) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
        returnedText.setText(errorMessage);
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResults");
        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        String text = "";
        for (String result : matches)
            text += result + "\n";

        returnedText.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
        progressBar.setProgress((int) rmsdB);
    }

    public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
        String message;
        switch (errorCode) {
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
                message = "Audio recording error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
                message = "Client side error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
                message = "Insufficient permissions";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
                message = "Network error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
                message = "Network timeout";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
                message = "No match";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
                message = "RecognitionService busy";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
                message = "error from server";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
                message = "No speech input";
                break;
            default:
                message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
                break;
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```