# Running speech recognition as foreground service (continuously in Android)

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, foreground-service

I am trying to build an app that continuously listens to what people are talking around the phone, and stores the converted speech-to-text in a file. Also the user knows that the device is in always listening mode.

The below code WORKS! (only to an extent though). It runs the speech recognition continuously:

- when the app is opened
- even when the device screen is blank
- even when I toggle to a different app.

However as soon as I press the Home button (center round soft touch button in Android), it stops working. The app does not crashes but it stops receiving audio.

When I click on the Notification card for this app (by pulling from the top of the phone), the app crashes, stating that the "Activity com.truiton.foregroundservice.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$Connection@188bc34 that was originally bound here" meaning that the audio device is already bound.

I am testing it on a Nexus 6P phone.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "ForegroundMain";
    private ForegroundService fservice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                fservice = new ForegroundService(this, new ForegroundService.onResultsReady() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResults(ArrayList<String> results) {
                        if (results != null && results.size() > 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Speech-to-text: " + results.get(0));
                            writeToFile(results.get(0));
                        }
                    }
                });
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
                startIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
                startService(startIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForegroundService.class);
                stopIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
                startService(stopIntent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void writeToFile(String data) {
        final String directoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "speechdata";
        File fileDirectory = new File(directoryPath);

        // Make sure the path directory exists.
        if(!fileDirectory.exists()) {
            fileDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        final File file = new File(fileDirectory, "data.txt");
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(data + " /n ");
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and the Foreground Service code calling Speech Recognition is here:

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "ForegroundService";

    protected AudioManager mAudioManager;
    protected SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    protected Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;

    protected boolean mIsListening;
    private boolean mIsStreamSolo;

    private boolean mMute=true;
    private onResultsReady mListener;

    public ForegroundService() {}

    public ForegroundService(Context context, onResultsReady listener) {
        try {
            mListener=listener;
        }
        catch(ClassCastException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
        }
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechRecognitionListener());
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);   mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                context.getPackageName());
        startListening();
    }

    private void listenAgain() {
        if(mIsListening) {
            mIsListening = false;
            mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
            startListening();
        }
    }

    private void startListening() {
        if(!mIsListening) {
            mIsListening = true;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                // turn off beep sound
                if (!mIsStreamSolo && mMute) {
                    mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
                    mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
                    mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
                    mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
                    mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
                    mIsStreamSolo = true;
                }
            }
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        mIsListening=false;
        if (!mIsStreamSolo) {
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
            mIsStreamSolo = true;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        if (mSpeechRecognizer != null) {
            mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
            mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
            mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
            mSpeechRecognizer=null;
        }
    }

    protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {}

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {}

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {}

        @Override
        public synchronized void onError(int error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR! ERROR!");
            if(error==SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY) {
                if(mListener!=null) {
                    ArrayList<String> errorList=new ArrayList<String>(1);
                    errorList.add("ERROR RECOGNIZER BUSY");
                    if(mListener!=null)
                        mListener.onResults(errorList);
                }
                return;
            }

            if(error==SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH) {
                if(mListener!=null)
                    mListener.onResults(null);
            }

            if(error==SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK) {
                ArrayList<String> errorList=new ArrayList<String>(1);
                errorList.add("STOPPED LISTENING");
                if(mListener!=null)
                    mListener.onResults(errorList);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "error = " + error);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listenAgain();
                }
            },100);
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {}

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {}

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {}

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            if(results!=null && mListener!=null)
                mListener.onResults(results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION));
            listenAgain();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {}
    }

    public boolean ismIsListening() { return mIsListening; }


    public interface onResultsReady {
        public void onResults(ArrayList<String> results);
    }

    public void mute(boolean mute) { mMute=mute; }

    public boolean isInMuteMode() { return mMute; }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
            PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                    previousIntent, 0);

            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.truiton_short);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Truiton Music Player")
                    .setTicker("Truiton Music Player")
                    .setContentText("My Music")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(
                            Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
                            "Previous", ppreviousIntent)
                    .build();
            startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
                    notification);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Clicked Previous");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "In onDestroy");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "In onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();

        mIsListening=false;
        if (!mIsStreamSolo) {
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
            mIsStreamSolo = true;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        if (mSpeechRecognizer != null) {
            mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
            mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
            mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
            mSpeechRecognizer=null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "In onBind");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.SpeechRecognizer$Connection@414ee400 that was originally bound here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930999/mainactivity-has-leaked-serviceconnection-android-speech-speechrecognizerconnec)

Comment: Sorry that's not similar to my question.