# Android create custom voice recognizer

Tags: android, customization, voice-recognition

I want to create a custom voice recognizer and design it the way i want.
This is my current one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql7QW.png

I want to create a custom one as in this app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmLkw.png

I saw few apps with this custom voice recognizer such as indigo, dragon,aivc etc.
I tried google developer solution for SpeechRecognizer but it didn't work for me.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

From this question: [How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

> Use the SpeechRecognizer interface. Your app needs to have the
>   RECORD_AUDIO permission, and you can then create a SpeechRecognizer,
>   give it a RecognitionListener and then call its startListening method.
>   You will get callbacks to the listener when the speech recognizer is
>   ready to begin listening for speech and as it receives speech and
>   converts it to text.

And then use whatever layout you want, and even animate it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I didn't quite understand what you mean can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Visit:
[Android( RecognitionListener) live speech to text preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715624/android-recognitionlistener-live-speech-to-text-preview)

also you can visit:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener

maybe it can be useful to you

By the way, you said in your comment that you don't fully understand.Recognition listener is a listener that runs in the background. In this way, there will be no unnecessary dialogs. I'm trying to automatically add subtitles to the video that opens, so I'm trying to do something like you want to do, but I haven't been able to do it yet.