# Android( RecognitionListener) live speech to text preview

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech

I'm using recognitionlistener interface in my app to convert speech to text. However I want to display the converted text from speech as soon as I speak. If I speak 4-5 words then 1st word should be displayed as soon as I speak it. In short like google assistant. I'm currently overriding it's **onresults** method and showing results when this method is called. Is there any way to detect one word at a time and show it one by one?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxHdMJXrMP2HRk80aVBtZHIxaDA[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxHdMJXrMP2HRk80aVBtZHIxaDA)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.util.Log;



public class VoiceRecognitionTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{

   private TextView mText;
   private SpeechRecognizer sr;
   private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);     
            mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);     
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);       
            sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());        
   }

   class listener implements RecognitionListener          
   {
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
            }
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
            }
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
            }
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onBufferReceived");
            }
            public void onEndOfSpeech()
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEndofSpeech");
            }
            public void onError(int error)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG,  "error " +  error);
                     mText.setText("error " + error);
            }
            public void onResults(Bundle results)                   
            {
                     String str = new String();
                     Log.d(TAG, "onResults " + results);
                     ArrayList data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                     for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
                     {
                               Log.d(TAG, "result " + data.get(i));
                               str += data.get(i);
                     }
                     mText.setText("results: "+String.valueOf(data.size()));        
            }
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResults");
            }
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
            {
                     Log.d(TAG, "onEvent " + eventType);
            }
   }
   public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5); 
                     sr.startListening(intent);

            }
   }
}
```

Comment: add some code...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you can, you need to override  onPartialResults :)

```
@Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
                ArrayList data = partialResults.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                String word = (String) data.get(data.size() - 1);
                recognisedText.setText(word);

                Log.i("TEST", "partial_results: " + word);
            }
```

Comment: In addition to this, I had to set RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS to true. Thanks!