# Voice Matcher To Match Voice Password in Android(Compare Voice)

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition, voice, voice-comparison

I am working on a App in which i have to integrate `voice-recognization/voice- matching`
    for `password`, this is for `Security purpose` and the scenario will be:

1). User `Register` In the app Via `Voice password`, i will convert that voice into 
        some media format and save it on device.

2). At the time of login user enter his/her name manually by typing and password 
        will be voice, then i will again record that voice and compare it with existing 
        voice file, if both are same then user move to next screen.

I googled and get [THIS](https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito), but i am not able to integrate this lib in android.

I am stuck badly on this part in my app, Any helping hands will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones

Comment: http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-voice-recognition-example.html

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4541

Comment: Mr. Downvoter, may i know that reason for your downvote?

Comment: what sorry man, give a reason to downvote.

Comment: i m not Downvoter there is alots of user u can check who Downvoter

Comment: You just said, you are downvoter.

Comment: @Dev Have you got any solution?

Comment: no, actually project got cancelled, however i was very near to solution that time, after i heard about cancellation, i quit!