# Style the microphone of android speech recognition input

Tags: android, button, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-text-to-speech

I am developing an app for blind people. Is there a way of styling this microphone

### https://i.stack.imgur.com/gejiA.png I need to make it screen sized.

```
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

---

Thanks

Comment: My intuition is probably not, but there may be a way.That looks like a dialog box that pops up to me.  If you could get access to the dialog, you could probably find (and replace) the image.  What do you do to call that box to pop-up?  (I've never dealt with those yet, hence the question.)

Comment: I added the code which calls speech input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vins4nity, I looked for a while but couldn't find a way to style the dialog that pops up, but you could do something like what this person did.

[How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

They just as a speech recognize in their own code with their own button and skip the whole dialog.  You'll have to change permissions a bit, but I think that might work for you.  Let me know!