# Voice Recognition without Google Dialog

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I am trying to use the Speech recognition without dialog with RecognitionListener, but it doesn't work. The following codes are the way now I use, and the bottom codes (test part) are for checking that could phone receive my commanding. Additionally, I have added permissions Audio. Finally, I don't want there have any button.

This is my first time asking question, so hope I dont violate any unspoken rules.

Thank you very much,

```
public class Step extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int SPEECH_RECOGNITION_CODE = 1;
private TextView txtOutput;
private Button btnMicrophone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_step);
    txtOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_output);
    btnMicrophone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_mic);
    startSpeechToText();

    btnMicrophone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSpeechToText();
        }
    });
}



private void startSpeechToText() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "SPEAK");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_RECOGNITION_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Speech recognition is not supported in this device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SPEECH_RECOGNITION_CODE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                String text = result.get(0);
                txtOutput.setText(text);
                test(txtOutput.getText().toString());
                startSpeechToText();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}



public void test (String com) {
    for(int i=0;i<com.length();i++) {
        if (com.startsWith("good",i)) {
            com = com + "123";
            Toast.makeText(CookStep.this, com, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    if(com.compareToIgnoreCase("OK")==0){
        com=com+"456";
        Toast.makeText(CookStep.this, com, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(CookStep.this, com, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

Comment: @Kaarel in spite of I almost copy the codes and it does can compile on android studio, that does not work on phone (shut down). I have no clue.

Comment: You need to provide the error you see in compilation output

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I cant run simulate the app on android studio, so i always make it to apk and try on the phone

Comment: Yes, speech rec does not work in simulator, it requires phone.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev when i want to go next intent where the speech rec, it would pop out "Sorry, (app name) stopped unexpectedly, please try again", but not whole app shut down, it just go back to last intent

Comment: You can find details in logcat window

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev do you mean on android phone?

Comment: Not in IDE connected to the phone