# startActivityForResult for voice recognizer intent hides some views in nested fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, voice-recognition, startactivityforresult

I have a fragment on which bottom bar `fragment` is attached. On the bottom bar I have some inputs which allow me to fill with voice recognition results.
I call `startActivityForResult` by

```
getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(descriptionEditText.getRecognizerIntent(), VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

My `onActivityResult` (calling from parent fragment):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            descriptionEditText.setText(result.get(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work good, but after the voice recognition intent is getting starting, the bottom bar hides for the moment, voice recognizer activity is active. I want to avoid it.

To be more clear, what I would like to achieve, there are some screen shots.

before clicking on voice input

[image: image1]

after clicking on voice input

[image: image2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, I do not want to get rid of a dialog. Just prevent killing nested fragments.